# Android XmlPullParser UTF-8 problem

Tags: xml, android, utf-8

I have an XML document built with

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer
```

This document contains following XML prolog

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
```

When I try to parse this document using

```
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
```

with following configuration code

```
XmlPullParser pullParser = Xml.newPullParser();
pullParser.setInput(theInputStream, "utf-8");
```

I get undecoded utf-8 strings when I call

```
String text = pullParser.getText();
```

So it seems that XmlPullParser in Android (I use 1.5) doesn't support utf-8. Did I miss something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it matter but can you try two things

1. Use `UTF-8` instead of lower case

And

2. Try using `pullParser.setInput(theInputStream);` and seeing if the `pullparser` can determine the encoding on it's own.

Comment: `pullParser.setInput(theInputStream);` did the trick for me - it seems that the BOM is correctly handled by `XmlPullParser` when using an `InputStream`

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but I recently ran into the same issue using XMLPullParser. In my case, I was parsing a stream of UTF-8 encoded XML from an OkHttp ResponseBody. It was necessary for me to specify the input encoding charset for this to work. In case someone else lands here:

```
override fun convert(response: ResponseBody): ArchNewsFeed? {
        val encoding = Charsets.UTF_8.name()
        val factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance()
        factory.isNamespaceAware = true;
        val parser = factory.newPullParser()
        parser.setInput(response.byteStream(), encoding)
        ...

    }
```